# How Can I Change Woocommerce Review Icons

Tags: css, woocommerce, review

Hey I need to change the icons I have in a Woocommerce Review system.
 Template - Flatsome.
To A icon image.
I want to change the:

```
`content: '\e005\e005\e005\e005\e005';`
```

To something like

```
`content: '\(img)\(img)\(img)\(img)\(img)';`
```

[How can i change this - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXfrW.png)

```
`.stars a {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: transparent !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'fl-icons';
}
.stars a.star-5:after {
    content: '\e005\e005\e005\e005\e005';
}
`
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating icons in iconmoon,
like this
content: '\e005\e005\e005\e005\e005';
*e005 (new icon number)

Answer (score 0):

You can erase the content and use a background-image.

```
.stars a.star-5:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url();
    display: block;
    width: x;
    height: x;
}
```

`
or create your own webfont, and override the font-family.